# jQuery Cookie Not Working in IE 8?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, cookies, jquery-cookie

***EDIT:*** I was having an issue with the cookie below so I switched to jQuery Cookie and still the error persist so I posted the jQuery Cookie code here but left my original question intact:

On one page I call colorbox and that code works properly yet on another page I changed the cookie name and function called and it breaks, here is that code:

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
$j(window).load(function() {
//I have also tried - $j(document).ready(function(){ - 
///to see if that changed anything

if(!$j.cookie('homecookie')){
$j("#start").click(); 

//the click functions clicks a hidden link witch triggers a fancybox 
//lightbox to load - works properly in all but IE (have tested 8) in which
//the lightbox continues to load regardless of the cookie

$j.cookie("homecookie", 1, {expires: 30, path: '/'});
}
});
```

How can I get this to work in IE 8+ - No errors are thrown when the page loads. Here is the page in reference:

[This Page](http://tinyurl.com/43naszt) Should Trigger Fancybox on First Visit Only

Note: I have tested the above cookie/script in FF, Chrome, Safari, and Opera and all work fine.

---

***--------Original Question--------***

I am using the following cookie:

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();

$j(document).ready(function(){

   if (document.cookie.indexOf('visited=true') == -1) 
   {
      var thirtyDays = 1000*60*60*24*30;
      var expires = new Date((new Date()).valueOf() + thirtyDays);
      document.cookie = "visited=true;path=/;expires=" + expires.toUTCString();
      $j.colorbox({ inline:true, href:"#gallery-nav-instruct"});
   }

});
```

It works in FF and Chrome but not in IE 8.

Cookies are allowed in the settings.

There are a couple issues, on one page the script is not triggered by IE (Colorbox) on another page the cookie is not reconizged and the script keeps getting called. Only change in the two scripts is changing the `$j.colorbox({ inline:true, href:"#gallery-nav-instruct"});` to `$j("#start").click();`

Comment: Which version of IE is it failing in?

Comment: Edited questions to reflect this but 8 is what I am testing. I have not tested other versions.

Comment: Are you able to use the debug tool ( F12 ) to try 7 and 9 please?

Comment: If you go into Internet Options > Advanced and uncheck "Disable script debugging" (both) and check "Display a notification about every script error" and rerun the page, are there any javascript errors?

Comment: I am on XP and cannot try 9 (correct?) and IE 7 does not trigger either script and generates errors (not related to cookie but other JS) IE 8 doe snot generate those errors

Comment: Always fix the top most error until you have no errors. Unrelated errors have a habit of causing side effects that are hard to anticipate.

Comment: @Homer6 - No errors in IE 8 (I am not checking IE7)

Comment: Also I know there are errors in IE7 but majority of my users use IE8 (or other browsers) and I have put a notice in IE 7 for the user to upgrade and the fact the site may not operate properly. In IE8 there are no current errors according to IE.

Comment: Posting such notices is poor style. Consider fixing for IE7. I currently don't support IE6 on my production sites, but actually block access to the site, as me.com does.

Comment: Are you willing to post your site?

Comment: @Homer6 - I will be asking how I can block access in another question later that is interesting. - I posted sites in question to each page that has an issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that Fancybox was the issue. I switched to colorbox and using jQuery Cookie it works fine on the page I was having an issue yet it [created another issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8116191/colorbox-not-working-properly-in-ie-if-linked-from-another-page) on another page that is a bit different.

Here is the code that worked:

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
$j(window).load(function() {
if(!$j.cookie('homecookie')){
$j.colorbox({ inline:true, href:"#home-welcome"});
$j.cookie("homecookie", 1, {expires: 30});
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to try this code? Does it work better?

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.cookie

Comment: Can you give an example - I know enough javascript to hurt myself and that page confuses me.

Comment: If you copy the above function, the samples are below in the comments.