# Calling a function based on jQuery Cookie

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies, colorbox, jquery-cookie

I am a bit confused and might be missing something in front of my face.

I am using [jQuery cookie](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) to create a cookie in my page. The code is:

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
$j(document).ready(function(){
$j.cookie("homecookie", 1, {expires: 30, path: '/'});
});
```

I know to read the cookie it would be `$j.cookie('homecookie');` but after that is where I get confused. I need to call this function `$j.colorbox({ inline:true, href:"#gallery-nav-instruct"});` How?

In other words if the person has *not* visited the page then colorbox is called. If the user has visited the page then it is not called. Can someone help me set this up properly as I cannot get it. Please give examples as javascript is not my cup of tea.

Comment: Is this the only thing you are using the cookie plugin for? There is an entry in the colorbox faq that covers this: http://jacklmoore.com/colorbox/faq/#faq-cookie

Comment: I read that when installing colorbox. That did not work properly in IE and had some other issues. I switched to jQuery Cookie because of it and I am using jQuery Cookie in other places on my site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply check for the presence of the cookie, if it is not present you can call function and set the cookie:

```
if(!$j.cookie('homecookie')){
    $j.colorbox({ inline:true, href:"#gallery-nav-instruct"});
    $j.cookie("homecookie", 1, {expires: 30, path: '/'});
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that works great in all but Internet Explorer! Go Figure. - I asked another question in relation to it not working in IE here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8109973/jquery-cookie-not-working-in-ie-8

Answer (score 2):

Well just check the cookie value:

```
if (!$j.cookie('homecookie')) $j.colorbox({ /* whatever */ });
```

Or if the exact cookie value is important, compare:

```
if ($j.cookie('homecookie') !== 'something')
  $j.colorbox({ /* whatever */ });
```

In both those examples, I'm assuming that you want to call the colorbox thing when the cookie is *not* what it should be when some user has never visited.