# .load event handler not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am attemtping to solve an [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8116191/colorbox-not-loading-properly-in-ie) I am having and decided to try the event handler for the `.load()` jQuery function. I am unsure what I did wrong. The example on the [jQuery page](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/) is:

```
$('#book').load(function() {
 // Handler for .load() called.
});
```

my script was:

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
$j('#gallery-nav-instruct').load(function() {
  if(!$j.cookie('gallerycookie')){
    $j.colorbox({ inline:true, href:"#gallery-nav-instruct"});
    $j.cookie("gallerycookie", 1, {expires: 30, path: '/'});
  }
});
```

Why did my script not work?

Here is the HTML related to that script:

```
<div style="display:none">
  <div id="gallery-nav-instruct">
    <h2>Gallery Navigation Instructions - Step 1</h2>
    <h2 style="text-align:right">
      <a style="text-align:right;" class="inline cw" href="#gallery-enlarge-instruct">Step 2</a>
    </h2>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p class="white">
      <img src="/Images/Pages/gallery-navigation.jpg" width="890" height="450" alt="Gallery Navigation Instructions" />
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have a way of confirming that the div isn't already loaded by the time the event is bound? In other words, it could be a timing issue. The load completes, the event is bound, but the event is never fired because the load is already complete.

I would be interested in knowing the problem you're trying to solve; rather than trouble-shooting the .load() itself (although that might end up being the tool after all!) it's best to allow room for lateral thinking. For example, I don't see why you couldn't do your cookie check and colorbox initialization on document ready. It may be that the image isn't loaded yet, but I don't think that would break user experience.

Comment: I will play around with it and see what I get as for my issue check this question out - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8116191/colorbox-not-loading-properly-in-ie  - I have tried document ready...

Answer (score 0):

Try putting your script at the end of the page. That might work. It will execute only when all the content is loaded as .load() event is called when all the stuff inside the parent is loaded completely.

[This](http://www.tizag.com/javascriptT/javascriptsyntax.php) should help you

Comment: When I moved the script out of the `<head>` it completely breaks the page for some reason in IE.

Comment: How would that link help? I understand basic syntax and there are other issues why the entire page breaks but not bad syntax. Or did I miss something? Thanks

Comment: I gave you that link to fix any syntax issues and how to put scripts in order so that pages don't break. I would require your code (where you have put JS out of head tag) to get to the exact conclusion :)

Comment: Okay, here is the page - http://tinyurl.com/6ub72og - I would post the code but it exceeds the SO limit. Currently the script in my question is the one I would move to the very end just before the closing `</body>` tag. If it must be moved for you to see I will create a test page for it as this is the production page.